# Implementing a Custom 'saveEventually (like in the Parse framework)' Method Used When No Internet Connection Available

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

I am developing an app that requires for users to be online when they save any data. When there is no internet connection, I save the data into `NSUserDefaults` with a specific key and then, if there is an internet connection available, I send the data to my server in **AppDelegate's** methods such as `didBecomeActive` and `didEnterBackground`. Having send the data to the server, I delete the object (i.e. the data) referred by a specific key in the `NSUserDefaults`.

The approach above might not be very intuitive. What I really want to know is how can I write a method like that of Parse (i.e. saveEventually method), which saves data to Parse only when there is an internet connection available? I would also appreciate if you have any other approaches to solve the issue.

Comment: What's the actual problem with what you've described?  (I can imagine adding a listener for reachability changes to have the server updated sooner, but that's minor.)

Comment: @PhillipMills I used reachability for observing changes in the internet connection. The problem is that the code I wrote is very scattered so that every time I need to save some data to be resent to server later on, I have to come up with a new key for NSUserDefaults and reuse that key in several places in AppDelegate. I am curious if some design pattern I can use for this purpose exists.

Comment: Have an object that represents your data model?  Keep your keys and save logic in that one place and have that object responsible for detecting when to save and where?  (Any object can get the notifications that match app state transitions.)